# Как сделать перенаправление на другую страницу по id?

Tags: php

Имеется страница, на которой пользователь выбирает нужный ему пункт и нажимает кнопку "Отправить". После нажатия на кнопку, открывается новый файл, в котором прописан скрипт на запись его значения в базу и нужно сделать перенаправление на прошлую страницу (она может быть с разным id). Переменная, которая хранит id у меня есть, пусть она будет `$my_id`. Как правильнее сделать перенаправление? Через JS `history.go(-1)` не получится, в сафари не работает так, как нужно.
Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обработали форму, записали в базу, и сделали `header("location: /view.php?id=$id"); exit;`

Comment: Благодарю. Пробовал через header, но что-то не так работало, видимо, exit; был обязательным. Спасибо огромное еще раз!

Comment: если у вас после отправки заголовков был какой-то вывод html кода, то должны были посыпаться нотисы о том, что редирект невозможен, не на страницу, дак в лог пхп.